# Nested Updated MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

Table - `galleries`

```
+----+----------+------------+----------+
| id | user_id  | is_primary |  photo   |
+----+----------+------------+----------+
|  1 | 1        | 1          | img1.jpg |
|  2 | 2        | 1          | img2.jpg |
|  3 | 1        | 0          | img3.jpg |
|  4 | 1        | 0          | img4.jpg |
|  5 | 1        | 0          | img5.jpg |
|  6 | 3        | 1          | img6.jpg |
|  7 | 2        | 0          | img7.jpg |
+----+----------+------------+----------+

UPDATE galleries set is_primary=0 WHERE user_id=1
UPDATE galleries set is_primary=1 WHERE id=4
```

There have a column name `is_primary` i need to set only 1 rows `is_primary=1` which user id `1` But there have already one row which `is_primary = 1 and user_id=1`

I want to updated `is_primary=1` which `id=4` before updated I need to set all `is_primary=0` which `user_id=1`.

I don't want to write 2 times query for updated.

How to write nested query for update my record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case-when` something as

```
update galleries 
 set is_primary = 
 case 
   when id=4 then 1 else 0 
 end 
 where user_id = 1 ;
```